# ->order('v.entity_id IS NULL') gets translated incorrectly

Tags: sql, zend-framework

`Zend_Db_Select::order` is translating `->order('v.entity_id IS NULL')` incorrectly to `` `v`.`entity_id IS NULL` ASC ``. It thinks "entity_id NULL" is the column name.

Any idea so I get the following?

```
ORDER BY `v`.`entity_id` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try with:

```
->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('v.entity_id IS NULL'));
```

Answer (score 1):

you should also try with below:

```
->order(array('ISNULL(v.entity_id),v.entity_id'));
```

Comment: Just need `->order('ISNULL(v.entity_id)')`